# Singular homology on $S^n$

Tags: homology-cohomology

Is it possible to consider $S^n$ as a $0$-simplex and a singular map of an $n$-simplex so that the $n$-simplex forms the surface of $S^n$ minus a point, and the point is the singular map of the $0$-simplex? Can a (singular map of an) $n$-simplex have zero boundary for $n>1$? I am trying to understand the homology groups of $\mathbb{R}^n$ with finitely many points removed. I imagine I could use the Mayer-Vietoris exact sequence and homotopy invariance, but I want to try to find the groups directly from the definition to confirm that I am right.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Homology Groups of $S^n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4009687/homology-groups-of-sn)

Comment: You have rewritten this question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4009687/homology-groups-of-sn). I can see that you improved the question by rewriting it. But in the future you should not create a new question to improve it: instead hit the edit button and rewrite the question. For now the best thing to do is to close this older version.