# Homology Groups of $S^n$

Tags: homology-cohomology

Is it possible to consider $S^n$ as a $0$-simplex and a singular map of an $n$-simplex so that the $n$-simplex forms the surface of $S^n$ minus a point, and the point is the singular map of the $0$-simplex? Can a (singular map of an) $n$-simplex have zero boundary for $n>1$? I am trying to understand the homology groups of $\mathbb{R}^n$ with finitely many points removed. I imagine I could use the Mayer-Vietoris exact sequence and homotopy invariance, but I want to try to find the groups directly from the definition to confirm that I am right. So, I have started by showing that $X=\mathbb{R}^n\backslash\{x_1,\ldots,x_m\}$ is homotopy equivalent (deformation retracts) to the wedge sum of $m$ copies of $S^{n-1}$ meeting at a common point, as in the diagram for $n=3,m=4$.[image]

Comment: You say you want to do this "directly from the definition" but you do not say which definition. If you mean the definition of singular homology, it is most certainly **not** an easy exercise to compute these singular homology groups directly from the definition.

Comment: I see, I suppose I am doing it by simplicial homology, which as far as I know is the same as singular homology, but I guess I haven't seen a proof of that yet.

Comment: They are not "the same". They are isomorphic, but that is a major theorem.

Comment: Now that I think of it, I think the only space whose homology I've ever seen directly computed completely using singular homology might be a point. Or maybe "two points". :)

Answer (score 3):

Certainly you can construct $S^n$ as a cell complex with one 0-cell and one $n$-cell, and compute cellular homology that way. Many algebraic topology books use this as their first example of computing cellular homology.